# IIS sending random request to wrong users

Tags: iis

We are running into a very weird problem with out production site. We have a part on the site that will list items 5 at a time. there is also a button to view all at once. When alternating between these buttons sometimes the list will populate with a search that another user is executing at the same time. It is as if that iis is losing track of who is requesting what. If you point the development server to the real database this will not happen. It only happens with multiple users on viewing the site. Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks

Further Info: We are using asp 2.0 with .net 3.5 . IIS 6 on windows server 2003. The list is being populated via stored procedure from a sql server 2008 database.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, can it be some idiot programme rwas using application state or static variables to store user selections (which exist only once), instead of session state?

No joke - seen exactly that (and a lot worse, also from highly paid consultants).

This would be one explanation.

Comment: haha thanks for the tip. I actually checked and the code is pulling from an query string which does not change.  It's really weird, say one collection is 1044, it will load that collection.  If you switch back and forth between show all and page view, the query string will still be 1044, but the list will contain items from an entirely different collection. I am stumped

Answer (score 0):

There might be race condition in your non-thread-safe code. This is not going to be easy to investigate.

Comment: i added some more info. Where do you recommend i even start?

Comment: General idea is to comment out code in your project until you'll find what causes the issue. You might end up in 10 lines of code reproducing the issue.